# Creating new user account and sending email for creating password - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Once the user has been created through my application:

- I need to send an email with the option to create new password to the user

So far when a new user is created that user is recieving the password reset email.

Problem is there is default email template for resetting password of Firebase: 
[image]

Need to **change text** of template of email.

I am using **firebase function:**

```
          auth.sendPasswordResetEmail()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) for your project.

Go under Authentication, there will be a tab called templates.

Click that tab and click the password reset section to modify the template.

[image: firebase console authentication templates]